# How to get a list of properties attributes?

Tags: c#, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I have created a custom attribute class

```
        [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
        public class Format : Attribute
        {
            public string           DisplayName { get; set; }
            public ColumnType       ColumnType  { get; set; }
            public double           Width       { get; set; }
            public bool             ReadOnly    { get; set; }

            public Format()
            {
                ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
```

Then I implemented this custom attribute in following ViewModel class

```
        public class GridTestData
        {
            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundInteger, DisplayName = "Auto ID", ReadOnly = true)]
            int AutoID          {get; set;}

            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundString, DisplayName = "String", ReadOnly = true)]
            string String       {get; set;}

            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundInteger, DisplayName = "Integer", ReadOnly = true)]
            int? Integer        {get; set;}

            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundDouble, DisplayName = "Double", ReadOnly = true)]
            double? Double      {get; set;}

            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundBooleanTriState, DisplayName = "Boolean", ReadOnly = true)]
            bool? Boolean       {get; set;}

            [Format(ColumnType = grdOpt.Column.ColumnType.BoundDateTime, DisplayName = "Date Time", ReadOnly = true)]
            DateTime? DateTime  {get; set;}
        }
```

Now I want to create a method that will take in my View Model class as parameter and return a list of custom attributes, such as:

```
List<Format> MyFormatAttributes = GetFormatAttributes(typeof(GridTestData))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your properties are not public you need to get them with `NonPublic` binding flag. Then from the properties you can get all attributes from the type you want.

```
var attrs = typeof(GridTestData)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(o => o.GetCustomAttribute<Format>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Type.GetProperties to get the list of PropertyInfo's on the type, for each PropertyInfo get  getcustomattributes()

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this:

```
public static IList<Format> GetFormatAttributes<TViewModel>()
{
   return typeof(TViewModel)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<Format>())
    .Where(a != null)
    .ToList();
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
var myFormatAttributes = GetFormatAttributes<GridTestData>();
```